# "The Czech Republic" versus "Czechia"

Tags: discussion, place-names-and-spelling

I have a concern about [this edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/26267/revisions) on [Crossing boundary for couple hours inside Schengen with children](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26267/crossing-boundary-for-couple-hours-inside-schengen-with-children). The name of my country, *Czechia* was changed to *Czech Republic*.

First, this is incorrect since the article *the* is missing. Second, both forms are correct, even the en.wiki page [Czechia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechia) redirects to the Czech Republic. So I would like to ask whether it's frowned upon to use the short variant. For me as a Czech person, it's fine and I actually prefer it.

Comment: I changed it to what is the most common usage. I've not heard about "Czechia" before, and that is why I changed it. I think it is important to be consistent througout the site. I wonder if you have ever heard non-Czech people use Czechia?

Comment: @Bernhard I don't know how many people use it, but I _do know_ I want to increase the number. Saying "the Czech Republic" every time is just ... ridiculous.

Comment: A Czech friend of mine used to just refer to the country, in English, simply as "Czech".  "In Czech there are many excellent breweries."  I don't know if this was technically proper English but it sounded fine to me.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's something I want to avoid. Czech is an adjective -- like English, and should not be used as a noun, it simply doesn't sound right. (I hope it's not too obvious that I'm strongly and exclusively for Czechia; for one, I didn't revert the edit `;)` `:p` )

Comment: For what it's worth in Italy we say "Repubblica Ceca" too while Cèchia or Cechìa are very uncommon (never actually heard them but [wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repubblica_Ceca) mentioned they could be used "informally").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Czech republic is most known name of the country. [FIFA](http://www.fifa.com/associations/association=cze/) AND [the UN](http://www.mzv.cz/un.newyork) using this name, but they use just Germany and not Federal Republic of Germany.
There is also a page about [the Name of the Czech Republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic):

> The Czech term for the Czech lands (i.e. Bohemia, Moravia, Czech
>   Silesia) is Česko. However, the English equivalent "Czechia"
>   /ˈtʃɛki.ə/ is rarely used in the English-speaking world (though it can
>   be found as early as 1866).

That's why I think it's better to use "the Czech republic". **However** it's your post and you can always do a rollback to older version of the post. When you keep the [czech-republic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/czech-republic) and use "Czechia" in the question's body it would be fine.

Comment: @Deprecated. [This answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3672/37602) should now become the accepted one.

Answer (score 10):

At the time the edit and this question were originally discussed, *Czechia* was indeed [virtually unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Czech%20Republic%2C%20Czechia&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3) in English compared to *Czech Republic*.

Nevertheless, the government of that country has recently begun a push to popularize *Czechia*, as reported widely in English media (e.g. *[NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/15/world/europe/czech-republic-seeking-a-snappier-nameconsiders-a-change.html)*, *[FT](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/f2b05410-0303-11e6-99cb-83242733f755.html#axzz48U31H8IG)*, [*Economist*](http://www.economist.com/news/europe/21697158-government-prefers-english-version-name-reminded-vaclav-havel-crawling), *[TAM](http://www.theatlantic.com/notes/all/2016/04/the-czechia-chronicles/479658/)*, *[SMH](http://www.smh.com.au/world/call-us-czechia-czechs-to-tell-world-20160414-go6was.html)* and so on), and the campaign has launched the website [Go-Czechia.com](http://www.go-czechia.com/) in support. I don't think the average English speaker had any comprehension of the depth of the controversy.

As such, I would argue that in the future we shouldn't stand in the way of *Czechia*; while it may or may not gain universal currency, nevertheless we would not suffer to replace every *Myanmar* with *Burma* or vice versa, nor *Côte d'Ivoire* and *Ivory Coast*.

Answer (score 4):

Travel Stack Exchange uses exclusively English as a language of communication, so all proper names are translated to English where possible, and the native spelling provided where necessary. When there are alternative names, the most common variants are preferred, for purely practical purpose -- facilitating external and internal search, primarily. In this particular case, using Czechia as an alternative name has a very limited appeal -- the official name of the country in English is Czech Republic, and Czechia, while it can be easily inferred which country it refers to, is just not known among speakers of English. The missing definite article is easily added, and you can suggest an edit to the post and it will surely be approved by a moderator or a high-rep user.

For another example, the name of my country is България, but can you tell off-hand which country it refers to? How many other users can? I don't think using this name exclusively is useful to people from 中国, ประเทศไทย or قطر‎ trying to find information about it in English.

Comment: The official name of Germany is "Bundesrepublik Deutschland" or the "Federal Republic of Germany". So I lose your point in _official name of the country_. And "Czechia" is an exclusively English word, the Czech word is "Česko", so I lose your point in comparing it to "България" for "Republic of Bulgaria". I agree that it's a less-known form of the name of the country, so I would like to know more details on your opinion on this. Thanks!

Comment: @tohecz His point about official name of the country, is specifically addressed as "in English". I think there are only very few non-English speaking countries with the same name in English and the native language.

Comment: But, we more often refer to "Republic of Bulgaria"  with just "Bulgaria". Which raises questions to me why actually "Czech Republic" is more common than "Czechia" , as this would actually proof your point. Language doesn't make sense I guess...

Comment: In English, the normal short name for the Federal Republic of Germany is just Germany. However, there is no normal short name for the Czech Republic: it's hardly ever called anything other than "the Czech Republic". This is unusual but that's the way it is. If you say "Czechia", most people will figure out that you mean the Czech Republic but they'd figure that out if you wrote "Czechland" or "Czechypies", too. "Czechia" isn't the English name for the country and it's not the Czech name for the country so it doesn't make sense to use it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The language argument seems to be quite invalid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic -- here, Czechia is listed as an English word ;) And most other languages use the one-word variant, none of them using "Czechia".

Comment: @tohecz The article you link to says " 'Czechia' is rarely used in the English-speaking world". That is *exactly* the point I was making: although the word "Czechia" appears in dictionaries, most English speakers don't recognize it. If you say "Czechia" to an English-speaker, they'll figure out that you mean the Czech Republic but they'll probably imagine, incorrectly, that "Czechia" is the Czech name for the country.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nevertheless, this sentence is simply wrong: _"Czechia" isn't the English name for the country_.

Comment: @tohecz Sorry, no. It is **an** English name for the country. It is used extremely rarely, to the extent that almost nobody knows it. To be **the** English name for the country, it would have to be either the only name used in English or, at least, the overwhelmingly most commonly used.  There are only two commonly used names for the country in English: "Czechoslovakia" (which is wrong) and "the Czech Republic".

Answer (score -1):

The CIA factbook makes no mention of "Czechia" as an English-language variant.
conventional long form: Czech Republic
conventional short form: Czech Republic
local long form: Ceska republika
local short form: Cesko
https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/ez.html

The United Nations calls it the Czech Republic.
http://www.un.org/en/members/index.shtml#c

Heck, even the Czech Republic government refers to itself as the Czech Republic.
http://www.vlada.cz/en/

Seems to me there's a fairly clear indication of the correct name for the country.

Comment: In light of the information that has already been provided in this discussion, I don't think it's particularly helpful to imply that the short name is incorrect (as opposed to merely rare) without much stronger evidence.

Comment: The CIA factbook has been updated and now uses "Czechia" as the official name.